# Unable to delete symlink from git

Tags: git

I accidentally committed a symlink in my git repo. When I deleted the file it linked to, and then deleted the symlink itself, I now get a generic error "Exception caught during execution of add command" if I try to commit the deletion in Egit. If I try to run `git commit` from the command line, I just get the output:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
typechange: /path/to/old/symlink
```

Why isn't git able to commit this change?

Comment: The real question is why git did not see the manually removed symlink from disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the file (even if it s a sym. link) should be done using **`git rm`** command.
E.g. **`git rm /path/to/old/symlink`**
and then use **`git add --all`** before you can perform **`git commit`**

Comment: You'd better use `git add --update` instead of `git add --all`, which will add new files to git index. after a file is deleted by `rm` command, you can use `git add --update` to stage this deletion.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm /path/to/symlink
git add /path/to/symlink
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push orgin $YOUR_BRANCH
```